# Is it possible to chain NS records?

Tags: domain-name-system, ns-record

Is it 'legal' and possible in DNS to chain NS records like this:

**com. NS:**

```
example.com NS ns1.example.com.
ns1.example.com A a.b.c.d
```

**example.com. NS:**

```
example.com NS azuredns.com.
azuredns.com. A x.y.v.z
```

The reason why I'm attempting such configuration is that one of our non-technical departments wants us to have all domains configured on our DNS system; but some of them utilize features of "cloud" DNS providers. I'm not looking forward to do such abominations, but I owe due diligence to my company :-)

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting downvoted - I know it's a stupid idea, but it's worth asking why _exactly_ it's stupid idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NS` records and their *glue* `A` & `AAAA` records on parent must match the `NS` records on the name servers, as specified in [IANA Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements).

> **Consistency between glue and authoritative data**
>
> For name servers that have IP addresses listed as glue, the IP
>   addresses must match the authoritative A and AAAA records for that
>   host.
>
> **Consistency between delegation and zone**
>
> The set of NS records served by the authoritative name servers must
>   match those proposed for the delegation in the parent zone.

This tells that if `.com` nameservers (`*.m.root-servers.net.`) has `example.com. NS ns1.example.com.`, the `NS` records on `ns1.example.com.` must match.

However, you can delegate further sub-zones just like your `example.com.` is actually a sub-zone delegated by `.com`, which is a sub-zone delegated by *root* `.`. E.g. you could delegate control over all `*.azure.example.com.` to Azure by `azure.example.com. NS azuredns.com.` which doesn't need to match the `NS` records for `example.com.`.

For the non-technical people in your company: **a company policy can't override global policies**, in this case the requirements regarding domain names and name servers. Actually, the IANA requirements are mostly based on technological limitations and best practices. They are unlikely to change as it would require the widely supported technical specifications to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I thought, thank you for providing links!

Answer (score 3):

The payload of an `NS` record is, as specified in RFC 1035, a domain name that specifies a host. A resolver will use that name to look up `A` and `AAAA` records, nothing else. The kind of pointer chasing you envision in your question will not happen.